# ChromeDriver fails to start with "cannot find Chrome binary" error after latest upgrade to 115.0.5790.102

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Went through a typical upgrade procedure on a Mac

- Upgraded chrome
- Installed new chrome driver version through Brew
- "unquarantined" it
- moved it to its default location -> /usr/local/bin

However, this time around the driver is failing to start, complaining about not being able to find the binary.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected the issue by setting Google Chrome binary.

```
options.setBinary("/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome");
```